# Forcing sound output through speaker in Android

Tags: java, android

Is there a way in Android to force output through the phone speaker, even if a headphone is plugged into the jack? I know there has to be a way because when you are talking on the phone, you can put someone on speaker phone, even if there is headphones plugged into the jack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change this system-wide using the [`AudioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setSpeakerphoneOn(boolean)) method.

I don't believe you can set this for a particular `MediaPlayer`/`AudioTrack`/`SoundPool` instance, but depending on your use case, you *might* actually be looking to set your audio stream type using [`MediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setAudioStreamType(int)) or an equivalent for other audio playback classes.

Comment: @Icemanind have you tried it this way? In most of the times you don't won't to disobey user settings like playing sound through headphones. But if your usecase is valid this sounds like it would work.

Comment: Yeah. What I was trying to do was create an alarm clock program for my own use for my own android phone. Sometimes though, I accidently forget to unplug my earphones and the alarm will go off through the earphones and I will not hear them. That is why I was wondering how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

First, I Added permissions in Manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
```

Then, I used this code

```
AudioManager m_amAudioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

    m_amAudioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_RINGTONE | AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
    m_amAudioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
```

Comment: Android studio says this is a "wrong constant". But with ` m_amAudioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION)` it works.

Comment: `MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION` is the same as `MODE_RINGTONE | MODE_IN_CALL` => `0x03 == 0x01 | 0x02`

Comment: Thanks for the permission part! 'Cause other answers I found did not mentions that and the `setMode` had no effect.

Answer (score 1):

Sound output through speaker

```
AudioManager m_amAudioManager = 
        AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);  

m_amAudioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL); 
m_amAudioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
```

Comment: doesn't work for HTC M9 and nexus devices :(, any alternate solutions ??

Comment: Doesn't work for Galaxy Note 10 either. But with `m_amAudioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION)` it works.